# Make n-bit adder

Tags: computer-architecture

I understand how 1-bit adders work, but I don't see how to make a 4-bit adder using those 1-bit adders...

This is my 1-bit adder:

[image]

How can I use this to create a 4-bit adder??
This is my attempt, but it ain't working because I event don't include a carry-in; and I need two 4-bit inputs.

[image]

Comment: "How can I make a circuit that does X" is essentially a programming question, which is off-topic, here. This question _might_ be on-topic at [electronics.se], but you should check their help centre. If it is on-topic there, you can click the "flag" button below your question here and ask the moderators to move it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the way that a ripple-carry adder works is to separate each column of the addition into its own circuit.

So, consider this addition:

```
A:   0011    3
B: + 0110  + 6
    -----   --
S:   1001    9
```

The first activity that you need to accomplish is to add $A_0$ (`1`) to $B_0$ (`0`) to arrive at $S_0$ (`1`).  This is done in its own circuit, similar to the full-adder that you've shown in your question.

So far, we need a circuit where $A_n$ and $B_n$ are inputs, and our *sum*, $S_n$ is our output.  So, two inputs, one output.  This is slightly different from your circuit.  Hold onto that information, because we're about to need it.

The second step is to add $A_1$ (`1`) to $B_1$ (`1`) to arrive at $S_1$ (`0`).  Once again, this gets handled in its own circuit.  And usually that circuit is directly next to the first circuit, so we now have two adjacent wires with (`0`,`1`) coming out.  And our circuit from before is still sufficient, because each $A_n$ and $B_n$ has resulted in a proper $S_n$.

Now, at the third step, things get interesting.  Because $A_2$ (`0`) + $B_2$ (`1`) can't become `0` without additional information.  We need a carry!

Suddenly, each column (each circuit) needs an additional **input** (the carry-in, or $C_{in}$), and each column needs an additional **output**, $C_{out}$.  We need these wires to facilitate communication between the different columns.

Now, we have three inputs ($A_2$ (`0`), $B_2$ (`1`), and $Cin_2$ (`1`)), and our $S_2$ of `0` makes more sense.  And we have an additional output, because we have to tell the next level of the addition that there was a carry.  So now, with three inputs and two outputs, we have created *your* circuit.

And we need one of these for each layer of the addition, chained together like this:

[image: (from http://www.circuitstoday.com/ripple-carry-adder)]